# launch app activity when reach gps location in android

Tags: android, gps, android-activity

I'm developing an app that have to execute some actions when the user approach a gps location (latitude, longitude and a radius). Is it possible to do it without have the app running? What is the best way?

Thank you

Alessandro

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On any device with a decently new version of the Google Play services, you can utilize the [Geofencing](http://developer.android.com/training/location/geofencing.html) API.

This will alert your app when the user is within a radius of a particular location, and your app does not need to be running all the time.

Comment: thank you, I've read your link and it seems to be what I need. Later this week-end I'll test it.